# CNSaveRequest.addGroup and deleteGroup don't immediately change Groups in Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

In Swift, when you update "Contact" by passing `CNSaveRequest` to `CNContactStore`, the update immediately changes Contacts in your native Contacts app.

However, when you add or delete "Group" (`CNGroup`) by passing `CNSaveRequest` to `CNContactStore`, the addition or deletion doesn't immediately change Groups in your native Contacts app.

In case of addition or deletion of "Group", you have to terminate and restart your app or native Contacts app.

Are there any ways to immediately change Groups in native Contacts app?

For example, in case of Code A, you can immediately see the change in native Contacts app. In case of Code B, you cannot immediately see the change, you have to restart either your app or native Contacts app.

I don't use `ABAddressbook`, so naturally we are talking about iOS9.

[Code A]

```
let req = CNSaveRequest()
req.updateContact(fooContact)
do {
  try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(req)
} catch {
  print("\(error)")
}
```

[Code B]

```
let req = CNSaveRequest()
req.addGroup(mutableGroup)
do {
  try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(req)
} catch {
  print("\(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I resolved this problem by myself...
I added the code that refreshes the `dataSource` of `UITableView` that shows `CNGroup` array. For example,...

```
var groups: [CNGroup] = [] // dataSource of myTableView

......

// Custome function to be called when you want to refresh myTableView
function refreshMyTableView() {
    do {
        // I forget adding the line below to refresh tableview datasource
        try self.groups = contactStore.groupsMatchingPredicate(nil)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Comment: That would fix the refresh for your app, but not presumably for the Contacts app? (sounds like a bad piece of code in the Contacts app, in that case)